# How do I repair a burner on an electric stove that is on all the time even if turned off?

Tags: electrical, repair, stove

I have a free standing range electrical stove and one of the burners stays on all the time even if I turn it off.

Can someone give me some ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The switch/heat control must have worn out or become damaged, such as contacts fusing together. It needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

I'll bet the control switch is broken.  This is not a difficult fix, but usually requires lifting the range top to access the wiring harness and install a new switch. Most appliance stores with a service department will also sell the parts.  If your range is a new solid state computer controlled, you may have a bad control board. If that is the case, the parts are expensive and should be done by a tech. they are very hard for a consumer to trouble shoot.